# PostgreSql Having conflict between group by and needing to add two more columns

Tags: postgresql

**Question:**

Find the landlocked countries which are surrounded by exactly one country. Report the id 
and name of the landlocked country, followed by the id and name of the country that surrounds it.

Output Table: Query3

Attributes:

```
  c1id (landlocked country id) [INTEGER]
  c1name (landlocked country name) [VARCHAR(20)]
  c2id (surrounding country id) [INTEGER]
  c2name (surrounding country name) [VARCHAR(20)]

Order by: c1name ASC
```

**Schema:**

- The country table contains all the countries in the world and their facts.
- 'cid' is the id of the country.
- 'name' is the name of the country.
- 'height' is the highest elevation point of the country.
- 'population' is the population of the country.

  ```
  CREATE TABLE country (
      cid         INTEGER     PRIMARY KEY,
      cname       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
      height      INTEGER     NOT NULL,
      population  INTEGER     NOT NULL);
  ```
- The neighbour table provides information about the countries and their neighbours.
- 'country' refers to the cid of the first country.
- 'neighbor' refers to the cid of a country that is neighbouring the first country.
- 'length' is the length of the border between the two neighbouring countries.

Note that if A and B are neighbours, then there two tuples are stored in the table to represent that information (A, B) and (B, A).

```
CREATE TABLE neighbour (
country     INTEGER     REFERENCES country(cid) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
neighbor    INTEGER     REFERENCES country(cid) ON DELETE RESTRICT, 
length      INTEGER     NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(country, neighbor));
```

**My attempt:**

Here is my original query that gets names and cid's of all countries that have only ONE neighbour

```
SELECT c.cid   AS c1id,
       c.cname AS c1name
FROM   country c
       JOIN neighbour n
         ON n.country = c.cid
GROUP  BY c.cid,
          c.cname
HAVING Count(n.neighbor) = 1;
```

The problem is that I also need the name and country id of the neighbouring country so I tried to do this:

```
SELECT c.cid   AS c1id,
       c.cname AS c1name,
       n.neighbor,
       c2.cname
FROM   country c
       JOIN neighbour n
         ON n.country = c.cid
       JOIN country c2
         ON n.neighbor = c2.cid
GROUP  BY c.cid,
          c.cname
HAVING Count(n.neighbor) = 1;
```

The problem clearly arises from the fact that n.neighbour and c2.cname are NOT in the group by clause. If I do add them in the group by clause then even if a country as more than one neighbour, the count(n.neighbor) will count each country's neighbours separately.

For example if Greece (cid = 1) is neighboured with Turkey (cid = 2) and Germany (cid = 3). Canada (cid = 4) is neighboured with USA (cid = 5) then the output of the second query will be

```
1  Greece  2 Turkey
1 Greece 3 Germany
4 Canada 5 USA
```

instead of

```
4 Canada 5 USA
```

How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way forward would be to

- resolve the joins you need for "neighbour", then
- join your first query to the result.

**Sample data**

Thanks for including CREATE TABLE statements in your question.

```
insert into country values
(1, 'Greece', 1, 1), (2, 'Turkey', 1, 1), (3, 'Germany', 1, 1), 
(4, 'Canada', 1, 1), (5, 'USA', 1, 1);

insert into neighbour values
(1, 2, 1), (2, 1, 1), (1, 3, 1), (3, 1, 1), 
(4, 5, 1), (5, 4, 1);
```

**Resolve the joins**

```
select c1.cid , c1.cname as cname, c2.cid as nid, c2.cname as nname 
from neighbour n
inner join country c1 on c1.cid = n.country
inner join country c2 on c2.cid = n.neighbor;
```

**Join your first query**

First four lines are identical to the query above.

```
select c1.cid , c1.cname as cname, c2.cid as nid, c2.cname as nname 
from neighbour n
inner join country c1 on c1.cid = n.country
inner join country c2 on c2.cid = n.neighbor
inner join (SELECT c.cid   AS c1id,
                   c.cname AS c1name
            FROM   country c
            JOIN neighbour n
              ON n.country = c.cid
            GROUP  BY c.cid, c.cname
            HAVING Count(n.neighbor) = 1) n2
on c1.cid = n2.c1id;
```

The final join in the query above guarantees that countries in the first pair of columns have one neighbor.

```
    cid  cname    nid  nname
    --
    2    Turkey   1    Greece
    3    Germany  1    Greece
    4    Canada   5    USA
    5    USA      4    Canada
```

Comment: WOW thank you so much! You explained it very clearly!